# Random Range with limits in unity 3d

Tags: object, random, range, unity-game-engine, union

I declared a variable of vector3 in c#  in update function

```
    Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(x, y), 0, 0);
```

i need value from 5-10 and 20-25 for x and y.

so values should be 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25

Usually i used to give

```
    Random.Range(-0F,-2F);
```

But here its not possible.
I dont know to solve this problem.

Is any union function to unity?

or any other method ???

Waiting for gentle ideas and proper reply.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array of the numbers `5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25`

Then pick one of the numbers at random from the array.

```
void Awake()
{
   int[] array = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24};

   int randNum = Random.Range(0, array.Length);
}
```

EDIT: I see you put the numbers as one set, but if you just need a set x and a set y. Then

```
Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(5,11), Random.Range(10, 26), z);
```

Notice the last number is n+1, since Random.Range is exclusive.

**EDIT2:** Use my class, it will allow you to pass 3 ranges and will return one number at random.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RandomSetGenerator
{   
    public static int generateFromRange(int range1Start, int range1Stop, int range2Start, int range2Stop, int range3Start, int range3Stop)
    {
        List<Integer> randomList = new List<Integer>();

        randomList = addToRandomList(randomList, range1Start, range1Stop);
        randomList = addToRandomList(randomList, range2Start, range2Stop);
        randomList = addToRandomList(randomList, range3Start, range3Stop);

        return randomList[Random.Range(0, randomList.Count)];
    }

    private static List<Integer> addToRandomList(List<Integer> randomList, int startRange, int endRange)
    {
        for(int i = startRange; i <= endRange; i++)
            randomList.Add(i);

        return randomList;
    }   
}
```

Comment: if i want 30- 35 also, how i can i do it. ?

Comment: Add it to the array:  int[] array = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35};

Comment: thats not possible. if i need values from 10-50, 100-200, 500-600.??

Comment: Can you explain your question better? It is a bit unclear. If now you want from 10-50, 100-200, 500-600. Are you trying to pick at random these values into the x field of the Vector3? Or does the set 10-50 correspond to x, 100-200 to y, and 500-600 to z?

Comment: My EDIT2 should take care of what you want. Just call that function in my class with the 3 ranges that you want.